# How to limit number of maximum parallel executing workflows in CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I assume that this can not be done via GUI (at least I did not found). Is there any 'supported' way to do this or it can be done in DB only?

Comment: What is the issue that you are experiencing that you believe will be solved by making this change?

Comment: I have more than 2500 parallel executing workflows which causing CRMAsync service to use all CPU on machine.. and that causing problems in other appliaction on same server. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the number of asynchronous jobs that can be queued per organization with a PowerShell script:

```
add-pssnapin Microsoft.Crm.Powershell
$itemSetting = new-object 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[String,Object]'("AsyncSelectMaxItems",100)
$configEntity = New-Object "Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Deployment.ConfigurationEntity"
$configEntity.LogicalName="Deployment"
$configEntity.Attributes = New-Object "Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Deployment.AttributeCollection"
$configEntity.Attributes.Add($itemSetting)
Set-CrmAdvancedSetting -Entity $configEntity
```

This option is introduced in CRM 2011 RU 3.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid that there is only Direct SQL Update method available - http://www.henrycordes.nl/category/SQL.aspx